# How to use device data from a C++ library in a follow-up analysis in another language

Tags: c++, api

I have an API in C++ which connects via bluetooth to a device and measures data.
Now I want to use this captured data LIVE and evaluate it in another language like R or Python, how is this done?
So I get live data from my c++ API from console applicaiton within visual studio, now I want to pipe this data stream to another "instance" like Python or R (maybe from within another IDE) and run my script on the data. Afterwards the data does not need to be piped back.

How is a good or correct way to achieve this? In the beginning I thought I would have to add native support for Python within my C++ project, now however I think it would be enough to just takes this little bit of data and pipe it to a local server instance where e.g. my R/Shiny application runs and read it in as a dataframe?

Has anyone worked with a C++ library for a device and piped that data live down another analysis setup in a different language? How have you done it?

Comment: The simplest way would be to print the data using `printf` or `std::cout` and pipe it to the other program by console command.

Comment: Is this possible for live data? So measuring one second and reading it in the next again over and over?  Can you maybe put this down as an answer(with a little more explanation)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you  mean by "reading it over and over".

Comment: @Nuke If any of the answer fixed your problem, would you mind accepting the answer ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use TCP/ IPC communication over socket.

In C++, implement a server which read data and publish it into a socket.

In Python implement a client which simply listen to a socket and process the data every time it's published by the C++ server.

If you want an easy C++ library for socket communication I suggest looking into either [ZMQ](http://api.zeromq.org/) or [nanomsg](https://nanomsg.org/) but if your use case is simple enough, using native [socket](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) can do the job simply and efficiently.

Edit : If you wish to go the ZMQ way you can start [with the ZGuide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/). You also have this [tutorial](https://osdevlab.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-send-message-between-c-and.html) about sending data between C++ and Python using zmq.
Nanomsg is a fork of ZMQ, so most of the concept of ZMQ will apply to it.

If you want to use native socket, there are already plenty of tutorial in both C++ and Python, just search on google.

Comment: Do you have quick guide for setup of this?

Answer (score 1):

If the both programs are independent you can just use standard system pipe.

You just run the both programs from a system terminal, piping the output of the first one as the input of the second one.
The syntax is usually:

```sh
cpp_program.exe | python_program.py
```

Then you just use standard output in the C++ program (functions like `printf` or `std::cout` which just write data to terminal). In the other program you use standard function for reading data from terminal.

This solution has a few disadvantages:

- Input/output streams are usually treated as text. If you want to pipe binary data there may be some problems. For example on some systems bytes/characters `"\n"` may be replaced with `"\r\n"`.
- You cannot take user input in the second program. (At least not without using some tricks to access real terminal input.)
- Pipes have finite size. If the second program is to slow to process data as fast as the first program produces them, the first program may be slowed down by print operations which waits for pipe to empty. (Or maybe it throws exception. I'm not sure.) In this case it may be a better idea to use a file as a buffer.